# delete duplicate rows using informatica

Tags: duplicates, informatica, informatica-powercenter

How can we delete duplicate rows from source database table using informatica.
This has to be done without using any other table. Means source and target is same table in Oracle database.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the Rank transformation to find duplicates:

1. Group by all columns but the primary key.
2. Check the `Rank` option for the primary key.
3. Set the `Number of Ranks` to be equal to or greater than the maximum number of duplicates you are expecting for a single record.
4. `RANKINDEX` will equal 1 for unique rows and every first duplicate, so use a Filter transformation to pass only rows with `RANKINDEX > 1` to the target and use `DD_DELETE` update strategy.

Comment: And how the delete operation would be performed? When you send a row to target, marked as DD_DELETE, it will try to delete row with maching key columns. Would this not delete all of the rows?

Comment: @Maciejg Although the question does not say it, **I assumed that the table contains a column ID that is its primary key**, i.e. some rows are duplicates because they describe the same instance of some entity (like customer or invoice), but each of these rows has a unique ID. If that's not the case, this method will not work.

Comment: Hi Marek & Maciejg, Can you please also suggest something when primary key is not defined in table. Can we do this using target update override ?

Comment: Hi Kan, the story of deleting duplicate nonunique rows in-place is quite long. Here's one article on it (although many have been written): https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/removing-duplicates-from-a-table-in-sql-server/. I don't think it would be possible from within PowerCenter without using one of the SQL approaches mentioned in the article.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my evil idea. However just as above there is an assumption that we have some surogate key that uniquely identifies each row. So here goes:

1. Add a `Lookup Transformation` with `Dynamic lookup cache` and `Source filter` set to something like `1=2` - we don't want any data to be read by the lookup in fact.
2. Set up the `Condition` to compare all the ports you want to use to determine duplicates (eg. all but the surogate key)
3. Each new row instance will be assigned the `NewLookupPort=1` value. Each subsequent instance (i.e. duplicate) will result in `NewLookupPort=2`.
4. Use `Filter Transformation` to discard all `NewLookupPort=1` rows
5. Use `Update Transformation` to set `DD_DELETE` for all the other rows.

As said, this assumes the existence of some surrogate key in the table.

Answer (score 0):

Here I am writing 2 approaches I can think of

If you are allowed to write Query in Source Qualifier
1.a. Write a Query in Source Qualifier and select the data for Duplicate Rows(i.e.SELECT (*
FROM table1 GROUP BY  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
1.b. Use the columns selected to delete that row using Update Strategy DD_DELETE

If you need to bring all data in Informatica
2.a. As its a table bring Sorted Data or use sorter to sort data on keys
2.b. Use expression to find the duplicates using variable as IIF(KEY_PREV=KEY_CURR,Duplicate)
2.c. Take the duplicate records forward using filter
2.d. Use update strategy DD_DELETE to delete the records

Comment: Navjot - This will delete all rows from table having duplicate values. But I need to keep one copy of record and deleting remaining copies. I think this is only possible if there is primary key (with update strategy).

Comment: Ohh! If there is no primary key then this is tricky but still can be done. Bring all the sorted data in Informatica (i.e. Select * from table sort by all columns in sequence)-->Use Expression IIF(KEY_PREV=KEY_CURR,Duplicate) to get duplicates --> Use Filter to filter duplicates(but still there is one copy gone forward)--> Now connect this to target.  Now go to session prop and use the property to Truncate Target Table to truncate the table before loading all the deduped rows in it.  I think this will work.

Comment: I have already tried this but it truncates the table and no row get inserted in target.

Comment: Truncate table is performed before Souce Qualifier reads the data. This way you'll simply truncate the table and there will be no rows to read.

Comment: Let's go this way. Use cached lookup with 1 extra column for Dummy join i.e.(Select 1,<Rest of table columns> from <Table to be deduped>) and use Dummy Source to start the Informatica MAP. Before joining with the lookup created (join key will be 1=1) to get all the data, use SQL Transformation to truncate table and then use the above mentioned flow to Dedupe records and Insert into DB. So here you'll preserve all the data in unconnected lookup's cache.

Answer (score 0):

I could think of two solutions, I'm not sure if these works though..

In the Source Qualifier, write the query to get the 'RowIDs' of the duplicate records and,

1. Pass the RowID to the target and delete the records using Target Update Override, OR
2. Try to delete using the 'SQL transformation' by passing the RowID.

Let me know if you've already got the solution.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Post might answer the question, little sample of code snippet might help out fellow programmers to understand how it works.